# Convert string of PHP array to javascript Object

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

I have a code that encodes a javascript object into something like this:

```
<script>
    var php_string='array("one"=>"value_one","two"=>"value_two")';
</script>
```

Now I would like to know how can I convert this into that:

```
{
    "one":"value_one",
    "two":"value_two"
}
```

The content of `php_string` is sent to PHP on a `$_POST` variable. Is there anyway to do that or should I use JSON instead?

**EDIT**

As asked, here is the code that made my `php_string`:

```
function encodeFormOptions(inputsWrapper){
    var the_serialize=$(inputsWrapper).find(":input").serializeArray();
    var text="array(";
    $.each( the_serialize, function( key, value ) {
        text+='"'+value["name"]+'"=>'+'"'+value["value"]+'",';
    });
    if (text.charAt(text.length-1)==",")
        text=text.substring(0,text.length-1);
    text+=");";
    return text;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I forgot to say that I need this conversion in pure Javascript. In other words, I need to parse the array string into a javascript Object because when a click on a certain button on my page occurs, I need to read the values that are currently inside `php_string`.

**EDIT 3 (The full reason of the `php_string`)**

I tried to abstract the problem but, now I see that I shouldn't have done it.

I have a page form that have some input's and multiple buttons named "options"

When I click on any of these buttons, a popup appears with dynamic fields (derived from the option selected on a select field) on it and, when I fill all the input's, I create the `php_string` and save it on an hidden field.

Now I want that when I click again on one of the "options" buttons, I could read what I saved on the hidden field, in order to put the default values that the popup input's should show if the selected option of the select field doesn't change.

The hidden field is then parsed on PHP.

Comment: Why wouldnt you use a native php array (by using array serialization in the POST) and then just `json_encode` it?

Comment: how did you end up with that string of a PHP array in the first place???

Comment: The answer to the last part of the question: "Should I use JSON instead" is a very emphatic "YES YOU SHOULD".

Comment: So I should do something like this `$array=json_decode($_POST["array_string"])` on PHP?

Comment: I think the real issue here isn't what you are asking. It's, "why do you have a string with PHP code in it?" If you want to pass an array from PHP to javascript, just json_encode($arr) and pass the resulting string to javascript...

Comment: Your `encodeFormOptions` function should have ended with a return statement after the first line. The rest was a crackpot idea.

Comment: Please, read my last Edit. Sorry for eventual error's but, I'm Portuguese.

Comment: **EDIT 3** still contains no reason not to use JSON.

Comment: @fab So is it preferable to encode everything into JSON via javascript and then decode it when I need in Javascript and in PHP?

Comment: @CristianoSantos sort of. Use javascript native variables in the client side, then encode in json when you need to send them back to the server and decode them via php. That's how most people would recommend handling it.

Comment: @Mahn so in my case, when I close the "popup form" with dynamic fields, I should make a `json_encode` in javascript to put the contents on my hidden field?

Comment: you don't need to "make json_encode()" for JS, it is readily available as `JSON.stringify()`

Comment: @fab Ok, I will use JSON then. I just didn't know if it was the best approach or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

It seems this may be closer what you are looking for:

```
<script>
    var php_string = 'array("one"=>"value_one","two"=>"value_two")';
    var php_string = JSON.parse(php_string.replace(/array\(/g, '{').replace(/\)/g, '}').replace(/=>/g, ':'));
</script>
```

It's certainly not the most elegant way to handle it though, so consider refactoring what is producing that output. For example, you could send json from the client and use [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) in the server side.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explained well my situation... I want to convert it to an Object via Javascript and not PHP. I will edit my question.

Comment: @CristianoSantos see my edit. In both cases however you would have your object in `php_string` though.

Comment: I think that I'm not expressing my problem well. This conversion must occur when I click a button and so, I can't have any PHP to help the conversion.

Comment: @CristianoSantos I see, if this is case you will have to modify the function producing that string to output a javascript variable, or at least a string that can be `eval` by javascript.

Comment: This works well. Anyway, I will change my code to JSON but, this answers the real question here and I will mark it as "accepted". Thanks anyway =).